Can computed signals have variable like functions?
In one of my computed signal I need to read data on a file, which is a runtime function. As I need the computed signal to run on client I need to figure out how to input variables. I try this:
import { render } from "preact";
import { signal, computed } from "@preact/signals";

const text = signal('This is changed on client');

const textAndData = computed((num) => {
  const data = `And this data is read on the server: ${num}`
  return `${text.value}. ${data}`;
});

function Result() {
  const num = 3
  return (
    <>{textAndData(num).value}</>
  );
}

render(<Result />, document.getElementById("app"));

Playground
This yields error: TypeError: textAndData is not a function. Is there a way to achieve this? I can see that if I can create the signal inside the module (i.e. useSignal, useComputed) then I don't need to worry about this. But for the sake of signal management I want to declare all signals in a module and export them.

if you don't want to create a local state with useSignal and useComputed the best you can do is to create a new signal for num/data. This way you can have it in one place, and updating num from wherever you need will automatically trigger an update for textAndData.
const num = signal(3);


seems like this is the only way? Having the signal as a function is still neater

Indeed, this would be the approach. The point of computed() is that it subscribes to signals, and creates a new signal from them. It's not a function that takes parameters.

@rschristian I understand the point of computed, but why is also having parameters impossible?

Because computed returns a (readonly) signal instance -- how would you pass parameters to it? I suppose I don't understand what you're asking here. It's not returning a function, but an object.
